# Can you print something in python without any built in functions or modules?

Tags: python-3.x

I know about sys.stdout.write() but that uses the sys module,
input("string") woulden't be valid either since it's a built-in function.

Comment: The point of having them be built-in is so that they are available to use.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what forces you to avoid built-in functions?

Comment: What would you consider not built in?

Comment: @CarlosHorn Because I want to?

Answer (score 0):

It used to be possible in Python 2, because `print` was a language statement, while it is a built in function in Python 3. But there is only a very tiny difference between statements and built in functions or types. And IMHO trying to avoid built ins is close to non sense in Python.